# Eclipse find and replace with regex is not working with "(?=regex)"?

Tags: regex, eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I tried to find and replace some tags with SpringSource Tool Suite(Eclipse). I want to change `<annotation-driven />` to `<mvc:annotation-driven />` but I don't want `<beans:bean ..>` to be `<mvc:beans:bean ...>`.

So I made regex like this(actually the regex is longer than this but I made it simple):

> Find:         `<(?=[^b])`
>
> Replace With: `<mvc:`

I added `(?=regex)` expression to avoid first character to be selected. It finds successfully but doesn't replace anything. If I remove the `(?=regex)` expression, it works fine but the first character is removed.

Is it a bug? Or Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I think it's a bug. I tried and it didn't work for me either. nothing to do with spring tool - it's a plain eclipse problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have used `(?!b)`, but `(?=[^b])` should work too.  Anyway, try this:

> Find: `<([^b])`
>
> Replace: `<mvc:$1`

`$1` should insert the contents of the first capturing group, i.e., the letter that isn't `b`.

If it doesn't work with `$1`, try `<mvc:\1` instead.

Comment: Wow, great! Your regex skill overcomes the bug. The `$1` worked. Thanks!